# Looping around a certain number of times

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to make this code only loop around 3 times as I do not need the 4th value. How can I do this?

```
{this.props.league.prizes && this.props.league.prizes.length > 0 ?
                            <View style={styles.section}>
                                {this.props.league.prizes.map((p, i) => (
                                    <View key={Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5)} style={[styles.sectionPart, { borderRightWidth: 1 }]}>
                                    <Text style={styles.label}>{this.getPositionString(i + 1)} Place</Text>
                                        <Text style={styles.prizeAmount}>{places[i]}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                ))}
                            </View> : null}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to stop the `.map()` after 3 elements?

Comment: yup, I think thats what I need anywa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the slice function: `list.slice(0, 3).map(..)`

Answer (score 1):

Why dont use make the `this.props.league.prizes` contains only 3 items?

`this.props.league.prizes.slice(0,3)`

or set `this.props.league.prizes.length = 3`

then you can continue render with 3 items showing only

Comment: Works perfectly thank you! other user was just ahead so giving reward to them. Thank you for help!